# Hide navigation bar when double click on UIview

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

How to hide the navigationBar on double tap and show on single tap on UIView without using the navigation controller? And also the animations when hiding and showing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(your_selector)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
```

In your selector:

```
-(void)your_selector{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     bar.frame = CGRectOffset(bar.frame, 0, bar.bounds.size.height*bar.frame.origin.y<0?-1:1);
                 }];
}
```

In this implementation you have only double-touch event that will change status of bar to reverse.
Unfortunately there are no easy implementation for single and double touché gestures at one moment. Much more human behavior and easy for you - work only with event of double touch.

[XCode project - example](http://goo.gl/tujDH)

Comment: Selector is not getting called also

Comment: Is it move? It must move to the top for it height. So if you bar at the top of window, it looks like "hide".

Comment: It's sounds impossible :)
Try to add: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.

Comment: May be you have any subviews? do you use you touch double times?
P.S. Don't say "not working", try to describe if working partly, or say selector don't call if not working at all

Comment: I wrote example special 4 you. You can download it and test :)

Comment: I have a table view in my view but the above suggested approach is actually stopping me to select the table row...any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

try this for hiding

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Hide bar animation" context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];

for showing

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Show bar animation" context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

navigationBar.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but with UINavigationController it's too easy...

Comment: what do you mean by hide bar animation and show bar navigation? Is it ok trying this code in viewwillappear and viewwilldisappear?

Comment: both are just an  application-supplied identifier for the animations. You can set any String for that

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `UINavigationBar` without a navigation controller:

```
navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f)];
[navBar setDelegate:self];
[mainView addSubview:navBar];
```

`UITapGestureRecognizer` is a concrete subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` that looks for single or multiple taps:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideNavBar:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[YOURVIEW addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNavBar:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[YOURVIEW addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Here are the methods that show or hide the navigation bar:

```
- (void)hideNavBar:(id)sender 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; //Animation duration in seconds

    navBar.alpha = 0.0f;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)showNavBar:(id)sender 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; //Animation duration in seconds

    navBar.alpha = 1.0f;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: @OdNairy, is it the method declaration or the animation code?

Comment: You changed it to correct variant. Also sender will be - UITapGestureRecognizer. You can replace 'id' by this

Comment: I have a table view in my view but the above suggested approach is actually stopping me to select the table row...any other alternative?